# Gtk# HBox container

Tags: c#, mono, containers, gtk#

I am new to Mono/Gtk development, so I am having some trouble in finding what I need.

I would like to accomplish a behavior similar to WrapPanel in .NET, meaning I would like to add widgets to container and have it go to next row when there is no more space available horizontally.

I also need to be able to remove widgets from the container randomly.

My question is: is there a way to do something like this with HBox/VBox containers? I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GTK has [`GtkToolPalette`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkToolPalette.html), but I don't think it's available from C#.